# "Waiting for target device to come online" Android Studio 3.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, emulation

Cannot start the app, the emulator opens, but the app doesn't. It says "waiting for target device to come open" and after 5 minutes it says "Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online." I've reinstalled android studio, reinstalled android emulator, stopped the android emulator, wiped the emulator and downloaded another one. Nothing works.

Nevermind, problem solved. There was an "Android Studio Emulator and “Process finished with exit code 0”" error which was half a second long. I created a new device with more RAM and solved the problem. Thanks anyway!!!

Comment: His emulator doesn't open, mine does.

Comment: Does your emulator run normally or is it also malfunctioning? Also, try running `adb devices` in the command line to check if the emulator is connected to adb.

Comment: It does run normally, yes. The terminal says: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.